# JSDoc broken on `exports.default` in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, export, require, jsdoc

I have a very strange experience with VSCode and JSDocs.

JSDocs information is shown for named exports, but not for default exports with the commonJS export method.

#### Problem: No info popup on `exports.default`

File: `index.js`

```
/**
 * Some explanation
 *
 * @param {object} obj The obj has to be~~~ !
 * @returns {void}
 */
function fn (obj) {
  // ...
}

exports.fn = fn;
exports.default = fn;
```

Then in another file:

#### Case 1: `import` import

```
import fn from './index'
fn // → no JSDoc info...

import { fn } from './index'
fn // → JSDoc info works
```

So it works on named import, but not on default.

#### Case 2: `require()` import

```
let fn = require('./index')
fn // → no JSDoc info...

let fn = require('./index').fn
fn // → JSDoc info works
```

So it works on named import, but not on default.

#### Gif to show exactly what happens

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t check but according to this GitHub issue the bug has been fixed.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41216

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
import { default as fn } from "./exp";
```